# Monkey runner installation

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner

I want to use monkey runner tool to automate some manual works in the android device connected to my PC.
I dont know where to start and what software is required to run monkey runner scripts. So is there any procedure to install monkeyrunner or is there any software like eclipse/mx-dev to start with monkey runner scripts? 
Can someone help me to start from the scratch?
Note: I have my ADB setup done on my windows PC and also android SDK, python are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Monkeyrunner has already installed in your SDK folder: sdk\tools\bin\monkeyrunner. There's no other setup procedure for it.